# how to display only number in python and suum/number

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array that contains numbers for example 90.01 90.02.. ,91.05, 91.06..

1. I want to make all the sum of 90 and device number of 90 and the
   same for the other numbers and put in a table how to do this in
   python example: 90.01 + 90.02=180.03/2=90.015 the same for the other
   numbers and put in a table how to do this in python??
2. I want to display only the numbers between 80-160

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhi0M.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of such an array (not only with 90 values)? And the matching expected output?

Comment: I added part of a table

Comment: it's neither minimal nor reproducible. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i just want a column of time not the other columns

Comment: Can you provide a minimal text example as requested?

Comment: example::88.1409+88.1409+88.1659+88.1659=352.6136/4=881543  the same for the other numbers and put in a table

Comment: Ok but what does this pertain to in regards to the image? Is it the average of the two columns for every row? This is pretty unclear ngl

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is unclear, but IIUC? you can use a dictionary and conversion to integer for the keys:

```
l = [90.01, 90.02, 91.05, 91.06, 88.1409, 88.1409, 88.1659, 88.1659]

from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean

d = defaultdict(list)
for val in l:
    d[int(val)].append(val)
d = {k: mean(x) for k,x in d.items()}
print(d)
```

output: `{90: 90.015, 91: 91.055, 88: 88.1534}`

Comment: but I have an array that contains several values 90 just an example and the output is an array that contains for example 90, 91,92...

Comment: @Narimane please read the help on how to ask, then write a clear question. You can't expect a clear answer if the question is unclear

Comment: I'm sorry if m'y question is not clear I have a table and I just want a code that makes the sum of a repeated number / number of value result it's a table which contains this value

Comment: @Narimane better than long discussion, provide a short sample input in the same format as in my answer and the matching expected output in a similar format. You said **I have an array**, can you define this array as python object?

Comment: but i have array i can't create like that 
l = [90.01, 90.02, 91.05, 91.06, 88.1409, 88.1409, 88.1659, 88.1659]

Comment: what is an "array" according to you?

Comment: An array is a collection of data elements

Answer (score 0):

[Original example that OP had provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DJTy.png)

We can do this all using `numpy` and `pandas`.

Let's imagine you have this file, which we'll call `table.txt`. Firstly, we need to extract the table from the file - let's use the `pandas.read_csv()` from the `pandas` package to automate that process a bit since we know we have whitespace delimiters (i.e. columns are separated by spaces and/or tabs):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

table_path = "../path/to/table.txt"

df = pd.read_csv(table_path, delim_whitespace=True)
# IF STARTS WITH HEADER INSTEAD:
# df = pd.read_csv("table.txt", header="...", delim_whitespace=True)
```

Now we've got our data as a `DataFrame`, we can start to extract the columns we want. We know they're the first and second column from the image posted (true at the time of writing), so we can directly extract those columns from our `DataFrame` and convert it to a `numpy` array for processing using the `DataFrame.to_numpy()` function.

```
columns = df.to_numpy(copy=True, dtype=np.float32)[:, 0:1] # copies data to avoid mutation (optional), slices of all the rows, only columns 0 to 1
# print(columns.shape) => (n, 2) for n rows and 2 columns
```

We can now create a new column of our average values and store that as a `numpy` array:

```
# average over column axis (1) instead of row axis (0)
# we can expand dimensions from a vector to a column of shape (n, 1)
average_col = np.expand_dims(np.mean(columns, axis=1), axis=1)
```

If we use `numpy.hstack()` we can stack them *horizontally* and create our table, then apply some filtering using a numpy `MaskedArray`:

```
av_table = np.hstack([columns, average_col])
# print(table_with_average.shape) => (n, 3) for n rows and 2 columns + 1 average column
filtered_table = np.ma.masked_outside(av_table, 80, 160).data
```

We can take this filtered table and output it to a CSV file using a `DataFrame` we create from our `filtered_table` array:

```
out_df = pd.DataFrame(filtered_table, columns=["your", "column names", "average"])
# print(out_df) => shows table in console
pd.to_csv("../path/to/output/with_average.csv", sep="\t") # \t means separated by tab characters
```

Comment: Glad I could help! I assume you're marking this answer as accepted in that case :)